# Draw image using mouse

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a web page where i can draw a image using mouse (similar to paint).is it possible in c# ,asp.net or silver light please help

Comment: `Yes, it is possible!`    Pardon my quip response, but the question is way too vague...

Comment: also i need to get the co ordinates  of all mouse clicks..pls help

Comment: @mjv- i just need to replicate the drawing functionality of Microsoft paint (ie) draw a image by joining co ordinates of mouse click

Comment: My point, Karthi! The broad statement "Just replicating something" doesn't typically provide enough insight into the requirement. For example, for a more fluid user experience, you'll probably want to manage the drawing on the client side, only reporting the resulting vectors, bitmaps or whatever format or object model you wish to introduce with the server.  Managing such canvas drawing on the client is a very different matter with Silverlight that say JavaScript.

Comment: Check out my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587843/how-can-i-prevent-fast-mouse-movement-from-breaking-a-line-in-my-drawing-app/9588143#9588143

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript to do that take look to this web site [jsDraw2D](http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/)

and this one [Drawing line in javascript](http://www.p01.org/releases/Drawing_lines_in_JavaScript/)

check th source of this page [follow_the_mouse.htm](http://www.p01.org/releases/Drawing_lines_in_JavaScript/follow_the_mouse.htm)

you can see it has mouse move function that you can get the mouse coordinates its not the final solution you should customize it!

Comment: i need to get the mouse co ordinates too... for example if i did three mouse clicks to draw a triangle i need to save those three co ordinates..

Answer (score 1):

Ya, its possible in silverlight by using the [Shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189073%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in silverlight. You have to use the MouseDownPoint and MouseUpPoint of the mouse capture to draw an image. The following method will show you a sample drawing of a rectangle in silverlight

```
void DrawShape(Shape MyShape, Point MyStartpoint, Point MyEndpoint)
        {
            if (CreateRectangle)
            {
                MyShape.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(SetColor);
                MyShape.Stroke.Opacity = 0.1;
                MyShape.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(SetColor);
                MyShape.Fill.Opacity = 0;
                MyShape.StrokeThickness = 2;
            if (DrawMode)
            {
                Temp = End;
                DrawMode = false;
            }
                if (Temp.X < MyEndpoint.X && Temp.Y < MyEndpoint.Y)
                {
                    MyShape.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, MyStartpoint.X);
                    MyShape.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, MyStartpoint.Y);
                }
                else if (Temp.X > MyEndpoint.X && Temp.Y < MyEndpoint.Y)
                {
                    double LeftX = MyStartpoint.X - (Temp.X - MyEndpoint.X);
                    MyShape.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, LeftX);
                    MyShape.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, MyStartpoint.Y);
                }
                else if (Temp.X < MyEndpoint.X && Temp.Y > MyEndpoint.Y)
                {
                    double TopY = MyStartpoint.Y - (Temp.Y - MyEndpoint.Y);
                    MyShape.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, MyStartpoint.X);
                    MyShape.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, TopY);
                }
                else if (Temp.X > MyEndpoint.X && Temp.Y > MyEndpoint.Y)
                {
                    double LeftX = MyStartpoint.X - (Temp.X - End.X);
                    double TopY = MyStartpoint.Y - (Temp.Y - End.Y);
                    MyShape.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, LeftX);
                    MyShape.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, TopY);
                }
                if (MyStartpoint.X > MyEndpoint.X)
                {
                    MyShape.Width = MyStartpoint.X - MyEndpoint.X;
                }
                else
                {
                    MyShape.Width = MyEndpoint.X - MyStartpoint.X;
                }
                if (MyStartpoint.Y > MyEndpoint.Y)
                {
                    MyShape.Height = MyStartpoint.Y - MyEndpoint.Y;
                }
                else
                {
                    MyShape.Height = MyEndpoint.Y - MyStartpoint.Y;
                }
                //Buttondown = false;
                //diagram.Children.Add(MyShape);
            }
        }
```