# How can I prevent fast mouse movement from breaking a line in my drawing app?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mouse-cursor

I'm working on a script that allows the user to draw with the mouse: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ujMGu/

**The problem**: If you move the mouse really fast it jerks and skips a few places. Is there any way to capture all the points without any skipping black spaces in between the drawing line?

**CSS**

```
#myid{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 3%;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -1100px;}​
```

**JS/JQ**

```
$('#myid')
.css('position','relative')
.unbind().die()
.bind('mousemove mouseover',function (e){
var top = parseInt(e.pageY)-$(this).offset().top;
var left= parseInt(e.pageX)-$(this).offset().left;
var pixel= $('<div></div>')
  .css({
      width:10,height:10,
      background: '#fff',
      position:'absolute',
      top: top, left: left,
      'border-radius': 2
  });
  $(this).append(pixel);
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myid"></div>
```

Comment: Probably a bad idea to do this with divs; consider using a canvas instead. Most browsers will be faster with canvas than divs, since divs require DOM manipulation rather than mere raster painting.

Comment: painting in this manner (using divs as pixels) is fairly limited. What are your requirements and what browser support do you need? Is there a reason you need to use this method rather than (say) canvas?

Comment: coz im not very familiar with canvas, and I need something simple so I can send this accross to other people in a complicated manner, as an overlay/mask on top of something else that is behind it.

Comment: @PhilH Divs can work if you use the right algorithm, Bresenham's is what I used to achieve this for compatibility in non-HTLM5 supporting browsers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm#The_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/KodeKreachor/9DbP3/6/

The following object on the given link contains the algorithm:

```
var drawer = new Drawer();
```

Let me know if you have any questions as to how I did it. The premise is based on Bresenham's line algorithm and should be compatible in older browsers as well.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to keep track of the previous point and then draw a line between the new point and the previous.

Comment: +1 for the idea, although "drawing a line" is not straightforward when your method of painting is to absolutely-position a series of 10x10 divs.

Answer (score 2):

As @kand has mentioned, a Canvas is really the best tool for drawing.

If you must use your `div` method, or if this is just for fun, you can extend your approach by saving the previous mouse position and then draw the intervening "pixels" needed to complete the line using, for example, [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).